# Observe does not trigger

Tags: meteor

I wanted to use the new observe feature but it does not seem to be working. At least not for me.

First things first here is the result of `mrt --version`

```
Meteorite version 0.4.6
Meteor version 0.5.9 (git checkout)
```

The goal is to create a bunch of draggable elements whose position gets reflected among clients.

Tis is my query:

```
  var items = Items.find({});
  var handle = items.observe( {
     changed: function (newDocument, oldDocument) {
        if ( newDocument._id !== dragged ) {
           $( "#" + id ).style( "left", newDocument.left );
           $( "#" + id ).style( "top", newDocument.top );
        }
     }
  } );
```

I know the positions are changed because when I reload the page the images get synchronized. I tried with both observe and observeChanged with the same result. If I set a break point inside the callback it is never called.

could it be because I still have `insecure` and `autopublish` on?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like it helps to remove `insecure` and `autopublish` but more importantly, to wait until the subscription is ready.

I ended up using the `Meteor.subscribe("name", function() {});` syntax and it works now.

here is the full code:

```
Meteor.subscribe("allItems", function() {
   var items = Items.find( {} );
   Session.set( "items", items.fetch() );

   handle = items.observe( {
      changed: function ( newDocument, oldDocument ) {
         if ( newDocument._id !== dragged ) {
            $( "#" + newDocument._id ).css( "left", newDocument.left );
            $( "#" + newDocument._id ).css( "top", newDocument.top );
         }
      }
   } );
});
```

hope that helps